# How to send emails in PHP using WAMP from localhost project?

Tags: php

I have a project folder say myproject in wamp/www folder. I have latest version of wamp installed on my system. I have abc.php file in myproject folder from which I am trying to send email. When I am running my project from localhost (localhost/myproject/abc.php), I am getting following error:

```
Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at &quot;mail.google.com&quot; port 25, verify your &quot;SMTP&quot; and &quot;smtp_port&quot; setting in php.ini or use ini_set()
```

How should I resolve this warning? Right not I don't have any mail server running on my system and I also don't want to run if for now. When I will host this site to any server, then I will use their mail server to configure my smtp. But for now on localhost,  how should I make myself able to send emails. I am trying to use ini_set method to do the job.

```
            $to=$_POST["email"];
            $subject="Hi Message";
            $msg="mail contents";               
            $headers="From: no-reply@mydomainname.com";

            //ini_set("SMTP","mail.google.com");
            //ini_set("smtp_port","25");
        if(mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers)) 
            {
                $msg="Email sent successfully.";
            echo $msg;
            }
            else
            {
                $msg="Email sending error";
                echo $msg;
            }
```

Comment: Gmail does not use port 25. It uses 465. Also, PHP `mail()` function does not provide authentication feature. Use 3rd party library like `SwiftMailer` or `PHPMailer`

Comment: You can't send mail from localhost without any third party api or if you are using a another SMTP for sending mail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SMTP class is the best option to send mail in PHP. Here is the link

http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/source/browse/trunk/class.smtp.php?r=170

Answer (score 0):

I'm a big fan of [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com) myself.